# How to install cpython3 and cpython3-dbg on Debian

Tags: python, debian, beagleboneblack, cpython

I have a BeagleBone Black running Debian GNU/Linux version 9.  I need to install [cpython3](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/cython3) and cpython3-dbg.

I have tried googling around the internet and cannot figure out how to get these packages.    If I type `sudo apt-get install cpython3` it returns `E: Unable to locate package cpython3`.

According to [this article](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), cffi supports cpython.  However, I found I cannot `import cpython3` into Python 3, despite having the cffi package installed.

Can someone please help get me started?  I am new to package installations.

**UPDATE: problem was I was spelling cpython not cython.**

Comment: cpython is main implementation of Python interpreter. It is not quite a module. For example, theres also Java implementation of Python, called Jython, C# has similar thing called IronPython, and even Python implementation called PyPy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's cython, not c**p**ython ;-)

FYI: CPython stands for the default Python implementation, which is written in C. Unless being compared with PyPy, Jython, IronPython and others, it's just called Python. The Debian package name for it is `python3` and is likely to be already installed by default.

Not to be confused with Cython, which is a CPython extension that provides C-like performance with code written in Python style.

Comment: Wow @Amie97 thank you for pointing that out!  I am going to edit the question and fix the wording.  Also, that fixed the problem, I can move forward now, I was just mis-typing into the terminal!

Answer (score 1):

Did you check out using the pip package?  try installing it this way

```
pip install Cython --install-option="--no-cython-compile"
```